# FreeBSD: How can I tune the lifetime for TCP/UDP for in kernel NAT?

Tags: nat, freebsd, pf

There used to be these sysctls in older versions of FreeBSD, viz:

```
net.inet.ip.fw.dyn_ack_lifetime=3600
net.inet.ip.fw.dyn_udp_lifetime=15
```

now on FreeBSD 12 sysctl reports that these don't exist.

How can I tune the lifetime for TCP/UDP for in kernel NAT?

Comment: They are still there. Did you forget to load it? `ipfw_load="YES"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Basically I was looking at the wrong documentation :-)

I'm actually using pf, and equivalent tunables are documented in the `pf.conf` man pages, under the section for the set command, specifically `set timeout` in this case.